# WordPress register shortcode with antonym function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

Is this a right syntax to register shortcode?

```
$field = 'sc_id';
$newfunc = function($field) { return get_option($field);};
add_shortcode($field, $newfunc);
```

I have collection of option I need to register all to shortcodes.
And some of them is working some of them does not.

Update:
Ok, this code works

```
$field = 'sc_id';
$newfunc = function() { return get_option($'sc_id');};
add_shortcode($field, $newfunc);
```

But I have about 20 values I need to register shortcodeds 
And I prefer

```
[shortcode]
```

instead of

```
[sc key="shortcode"]
```

How I can do this?

Before 7.2 php 
this code was work for me

```
$newfunc = create_function('', 'return get_option(' . $field . ');');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right syntax. Look at the [wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode).

You can try something like this:

```
$field = 'sc_id';
$newfunc = function($atts) { return get_option($atts['key']);};
add_shortcode($field, $newfunc);
```

and call the shortcode like this:

```
[sc_id key="option_key"]
```

---

EDIT because of comment question:

When u want multile shortcodes for multiple fields without attributes, u can use somethink like this:

```
$fields = array('sc_id','sc_it','sc_ib'); 
foreach($fields as $field) { 
    $newfunc = function() use($field) { 
        return get_option($field);
    }
    add_shortcode($field, $newfunc); 
}
```

With the `use` keyword we can pass outer scopes variables into our anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me ask like this
I have a collection of options in the database
`echo get_option('sc_id');
echo get_option('sc_it');
echo get_option('sc_ib');
`
And I need to create the same amount of shortcodes, I don't need options like  
` [sc_id key="option_key"] `
I need to register this shortcodes ` [sc_id],[sc_it],[sc_ib] `
Is this right syntax? 
' $fields = array('sc_id','sc_it','sc_ib');
 foreach($fields as $field) {
     $newfunc = function() { return get_option($field);};
     add_shortcode($field, $newfunc);
            } `